# How to send keys in web page using tag

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Given this HTML:

```html
<div class="divSearchContainer"><input type="search" class="FL H100P" placeholder="Select"><div class="divSearchIconConatiner H100P CP FL" title="Search"><div class="divSearchIcon"></div></div>
```

I'm using this code to send the keys:

```py
self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name("FL.H100P").send_keys('Test')
```

But I'm getting this error:

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "<string>", line 1, in <module> AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_elements_by_class_name'`

Answer (score 1):

There are three issues with using `driver.find_elements_by_class_name()`:

- That method has been removed in newer selenium versions.
- That returns a list of elements when it looks like you just want to click one.
- Since there are multiple classes, you should probably use `.` (dot) notation with a `css selector`.

This is probably what you want:

```py
self.driver.find_element("css selector", "input.H100P").send_keys("Test")
```

But, since the `H100P` looks auto-generated, and may change, you probably want to use this instead (if there's only one search input on that page):

```py
self.driver.find_element("css selector", 'input[type="search"]').send_keys("Test")
```